# Did I create additional branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am cloning this particular repo in which it initially already has a Pull Request done by one of my colleague but I was not made aware of it..

Basically, this is what I did:

- git clone
- git branch -a
- git checkout -b remotes/origin/feature/Issue01
  remotes/origin/feature/Issue01
- Make changes to the repo etc etc
- git add, git commit, git push
- Open a Pull Request

It was only at my PR page (I am using Atlassian), then I realized that my colleague has actually opened up another PR, which is still open but his branch naming is different from mine..

This is evidenced by the top part of the PR page which shows the name of branch and which to be merged..

- My colleague : `feature/Issue01 -> develop`
- My version :  `remotes/origin/feature/Issue01 -> develop`

My questions here is: 
1. am I creating an additional branch? If so, will this cause any issues if they were merged into the develop?

2. If I am trying to make my branch name to be the same as my colleague's branch, is this the command I should have typed instead: `git checkout -b  feature/Issue01 remotes/origin/feature/Issue01`

Comment: Yes, you did create an additional branch. That's what [`git checkout -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) does.

Comment: I should clarify that you created a new _local_ branch. It looks like your local branch is tracking the `develop` upstream branch. That's probably not what you wanted. Were you expecting to be working code in `feature/Issue01` that already exists?

Comment: @mkasberg Yes, I am expecting to work my stuff in the branch `feature/Issue01`. But it does seems that I have created another unnecessary branch. In that case, what should be the correct workflow then? To my understanding, `git checkout -b` is required so that I can create a local branch while it tracks the `feature/Issue01`, or am I wrong in this case?

Comment: You currently have a local branch named `remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` tracking the remote branch `develop`. That's probably going to cause problems for you in the future, so I'd delete that local branch if I were you (after saving code elsewhere). You can do that with `git branch -d`.

Answer (score 2):

[`git checkout -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is used to create a new local branch. You're not using it quite right.

The easiest way to do what I think you're trying to do is `git checkout feature/Issue01`. If that branch doesn't exist locally (it shouldn't), git will detect that it does exist upstream, and it will pull it and set up tracking info for you.

On any branch, you can use `git branch -u origin/feature/Issue01` to have the local brancy *that you're currently on* track whatever upstream branch you specify.

---

Alternatively, something like this would work: `$ git checkout -b feature/Issue01 --track origin/feature/Issue01`

Comment: I see. Then I guess mistake would be blindly copying and pasting in `remotes/origin/...` for the checkout then, causing a new branch creation.. But now that I have pushed and committed my `remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` into my repo as a PR, will `git branch -d` resolves the issue?

Comment: Also can I assume that while using the first method that you suggest, `remotes/origin/` should not be added into the command?

Comment: You should decline the PR, then use whatever mechanism the server software uses to delete the branch on the remote, or use `git push <remote> :<branch>` if that will work(some server stacks don't like it). Then `git branch -d` to clean up your local branch.

Comment: Depends how you pushed. Your local branch `remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` was tracking remote branch `develop`. So if you let git pick the branch to push to, it would have pushed to develop. If you told git where to push it, see Darren's comment.